# How to create a variable (predictor) that reflects the level of difference between a observations and others ones?

Tags: r, supervised-learning, feature-engineering

I have a medical-related data (training set) like this:

```
doctor  evaluation    patient  question
A       excellent     01       diet 
A       excellent     01       allergen
A       excellent     01       age
A       excellent     02       allergen
A       excellent     02       medical record
A       excellent     02       family history
B       normal       03       diet 
B       normal       03       allergen
B       normal       04       diet
B       normal       04       allergen
B       normal       05       diet
B       normal       05       allergen
...(3,000 doctors' data)
```

Each observation represent a doctor-patient diagnosis question themes.
And the evaluation column is the label I would like to predict.

Here I would like to know the characteristics of excellent doctors by using a new variable, which is, compared with general doctors, excellent doctors will ask different questions for different patients. In other words, how to create a variable stands for the 'versatility' from the question column.

Could anyone en-light me some ideas?

Comment: I don't know how you would create a new variable from this, you could do clustering to find out what questions are predominantly asked by doctors that give excellent evaluation (compared to normal), but to determine why that doctor did so you would probably need more information about the doctor (education, age, experience, ...).

Comment: What you call "versatility" is better known as *diversity*, for instance in ecology there are measures of biodiversity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biodiversity   and especially  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index.  So you would use the *diversity* of the different questions asked.

Comment: There is votes to close as unclear, but it seems clear enough to me!

Answer (score 0):

If you use *Shannon index* which is one the *diversity index*(mentioned in above comment), you may create a variable like this:

Suppose you have *n* different kinds of question in total, this is maybe the

```
n <- n_distinct(df$question)
```

then calculate the proportion of each question,

```
P <- table(df$question) / nrow(df)
```

here *p* has *n* elements.

after that, calculate the *Shannon index*:

```
Shannon_div_index <- -(p * exp(p))
```

fro each question.

The R code above is not very rigorous, however, hopefully, this can bring you some new idea.